# Can you substitute blood for the eggs in an ice cream base?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, culinary-uses, ice-cream

I read somewhere ([Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152745807046681&set=gm.526817074123299&type=1&theater)) that you can use blood as a substitute for the eggs in an ice cream base due to to the similarities in protein composition shared between the two.

Does anyone know more about this?

Have you made Blood Ice Cream?

What would be some good flavors?

Would the blood give the ice cream a metallic flavor because of bloods high content of iron?

Comment: Sounds like an urban legend to me... But from years of nosebleed-proneness and as a woman (you know...) I can confirm that even small traces have a distinct flavour and smell. So nothing that would be easily masked, IMHO. Good for a bunch of very fearless Halloween guests, perhaps, if you can get your hands on the stuff - not easy nowadays, I heard.

Comment: I stand corrected on the urban legend part - see my answer below.

Comment: @Stephie I have a lot of fellow culinary arts graduate peers

Comment: How about bacon egg and blackpudding instead 

Comment: @Chef_Code Sure, but the picture was of blood orange sorbet, no ice cream and no blood, so it wasn't particularly credible at first glance...

Comment: To me this sounds like a case where technically you *can*, but you really, *really shouldn't*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nordic Food Lab, founded by René Redzepi, has experimented with blood as egg substitute, full blog entry including recipes [here](http://nordicfoodlab.org/blog/2013/9/blood-and-egg).

Apparently texture-wise the substitution can be possible, but the typical bloody aftertaste is hard to mask, which might have to do with the physiological way the metallic taste is perceived. It seems especially women tend to recognize this ingredient quite easily.

Comment: nice find, interesting article.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the claims aren't fake (see [Stephie's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/56808/1672)) but the photo sure is.

The photo is of blood orange sorbet, from [this blog](http://www.feastingathome.com/2013/02/blood-orange-sorbet.html):

[image: blood orange sorbet]

(I'm assuming the blog is the original source; I can't find any other instances of the picture online, and they have a lot of other photos of the same thing along with it.)

The photo definitely *looks* like sorbet and not ice cream; it's icy not creamy. The flavor and safety issues would probably be a deal-breaker anyways.

Comment: Good find of this picture! But apparently the chef behind Noma *has* done some experiments with blood. So there seems to be a grain of truth in this facebook claim, sigh!

Comment: @Stephie Ugh, well, kudos to you for digging that up. The captioned image is still pretty dishonest, between omitting the flavor issues and using a photo of something that's not even ice cream.

Comment: Absolutely! And I somehow don't see me replicating these experiments either...